# JSplumb double bonds

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsplumb

I would like make a double bonds with two div using librairy jsPlumb Javascript. I can make a connection, but not a double bonds.

Do you know how to make a double bond ?

For a simple link between two DIV:

> ```
> jsPlumb.ready(function() {
>    jsPlumb.importDefaults({
>        ConnectorZIndex:5
>    });
>    var jsP = jsPlumb.getInstance({
>        PaintStyle:{ lineWidth:2, strokeStyle:"#000", outlineColor:"black", outlineWidth:1 },
>        Connector: "Straight",
>        Endpoint: "Blank"
>    });
>    var e0 = jsP.addEndpoint("firstLink", {
>            anchor: ["Center"]
>    });
>    var e1 = jsP.addEndpoint("lastLink", {
>            anchor: ["Center"]
>    });
>    jsP.connect({ source:e0, target:e1});
> ```

For a double link in two DIV, I test this, but it doesn't work:

> ```
>        var e0 = jsP.addEndpoint("firstLink", {
>            anchor: ["Center"]
>        });
>       var e1 = jsP.addEndpoint("lastLink", {
>            anchor: ["Center"]
>
>        });
>       var e2 = jsP.addEndpoint("firstLink", {
>            anchor: ["Center"]
>        });
>       var e3 = jsP.addEndpoint("lastLink", {
>            anchor: ["Left"]
>
>        });
>       jsP.connect({ source:e0, target:e1});
>       jsP.connect({ source:e2, target:e3});
> ```

Somebody have a solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Left" is not a valid anchor location in jsPlumb.  Try "LeftMiddle", "TopLeft" or "BottomLeft".  "LeftMiddle" is probably the one you're looking for.

Comment: This is almost what I want. The spacing between the link is to bigger. Can I determinate a spacing. For example, 5px between two connection ?